# Dynamically Changing Menu via Jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At one point, based upon the status of a toggle switch, I need a menu that you can have multiple options or one option. These menus are located in Jquery Tabs. If I make a new tab, the menu is correctly populated. If I try to swap the menu in an existing tab, then it doesn't quite work. First there is no checkbox on the right (or it remains when it shouldn't) and the menu doesn't quite update until I click something.

Here's the code that gets called every time my toggle switch is flipped.

```
function setPicker(){
    var currentTab = globalCurrentTab;
    var exchange = currentTab.attr("exchange");
    var symbol = currentTab.attr("symbol");    
    if($("#flip-min option:selected").html() == "Graph") {  //no multiple attribute
        $('#select-choice-'+symbol+'-'+exchange).empty();
        $('#select-choice-'+symbol+'-'+exchange).removeAttr('multiple');
        $('#select-choice-'+symbol+'-'+exchange).append('<option>Choose Fields</option>');
        $('#select-choice-'+symbol+'-'+exchange).append('<option value=1>My option1</option>');
        $('#select-choice-'+symbol+'-'+exchange).append('<option value=2>My option2</option>');
        $('#select-choice-'+symbol+'-'+exchange).append('<option value=3>My option3</option>');


    }
    else { //yes multiple attribute
        $('#select-choice-'+symbol+'-'+exchange).find('option').remove().end();
        $('#select-choice-'+symbol+'-'+exchange).attr('multiple','multiple');
        $('#select-choice-'+symbol+'-'+exchange).append('<option>Choose Fields</option>');
        $('#select-choice-'+symbol+'-'+exchange).append('<option value=1>My option1</option>');
        $('#select-choice-'+symbol+'-'+exchange).append('<option value=2>My option2</option>');
        $('#select-choice-'+symbol+'-'+exchange).append('<option value=3>My option3</option>');
        $('#select-choice-'+symbol+'-'+exchange).append('<option value=4>My option4</option>');
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why not just use separate selects and hide whichever is irrelevant?

Comment: Can you put up a fiddle that duplicates the problem so we can take a closer look?

Comment: BTW, learn how to use method chaining, so you don't have to repeat `$('#select-choice-'+symbol+'-'+exchange)` on every line.

Comment: And you don't need to use `.end()` if you're not chaining anything to that.

Comment: @user3334690, that was a really good suggestion and has the side effect of preserving the selection when switching tabs. If you put that as the answer, I'll mark it as it. Thanks to everyone else as well.